# Check for space in string in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I want to read a string and split it into words and check if there is a space after each word. I tried the below logic however how can I know if there's a space after DATABASE_URL.

```
#! /bin/bash

string="/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir/5/data.sql;DATABASE_URL ;5;value;/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/output.sql"

IFS=';'

read -ra arr <<< "$string"

# Print each value of the array by using the loop
for val in "${arr[@]}";
do
  printf "name = $val\n"
done
```

Output of above script:

```
name = /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir/5/data.sql
name = DATABASE_URL
name = 5
name = value
name = /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/output.sql
```

Help here would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to do in script when there is a space present?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `grep` to check if word ends with a space, like so: `grep " $"`.

```sh
#! /bin/bash

string="/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir/5/data.sql;DATABASE_URL ;5;value;/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/output.sql"

IFS=';'

read -ra arr <<< "$string"

# Print each value of the array by using the loop
for val in "${arr[@]}";
do
  echo $val | grep -q " $" && echo -ne "Contains space at the end: "
  printf "name = $val\n"
done
```

Output:

```
amvara@development:/tmp$ ./test.sh
name = /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir/5/data.sql
Contains space at the end: name = DATABASE_URL
name = 5
name = value
name = /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/output.sql
```